# Passing on Salesforce records to Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to pass contact records from Salesforce into the Marketing Cloud to get them onto a journey and to do a few guided sends.
I noticed that Salesforce Data Extensions could not be used for guided send. So,
I am thinking of using custom Data Extension. My question is how should I map it to the contact field and setup the API so that whenever a contact is created in Salesforce it is passed to ExactTarget.
Thanks in advance for your help.Would appreciate if you could direct me to the best practice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce Data Extensions can definitely be used in a guided send - are you perhaps referring to a Synchronized Data Extension?

A Salesforce Data Extension is created when you do an Import Activity of your Lead or Contact object from Salesforce. These are sendable and can be placed into an automation to bring in new records hourly, as an example.

A Synchronized Data Extension is created through Contact Builder and involves a refresh as often as 15 minutes to bring in data from Salesforce objects into Marketing Cloud Data Extensions. These may sendable, but you can't select them from a Guided send (yet).

If you are referring to a Synchronized Data Extension I would advise one of the following:

- Create a filter on the Data Extension and save it in an accessible folder outside of the Synchronized folder
- Create a copy data extension and query its contents into the accessible sendable Data Extension

Regardless if you end goal is to have them in a Journey you will likely want to query the data coming in to create the appropriate segments. You may also want to directly use the Salesforce Journey Builder activities - I haven't used them yet personally but they seem to be able to access your data directly from Salesforce.

Hope that helps!